# How to pass kernel parameters on EC2 HVM boot?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I want to specify root=/dev/xvdf1

There is no console.

Is it Possible to change the boot device on EC2?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. There is no interactive console when the EC2 instances boot in which to interrupt the boot to enter the kernel parameters.

The workaround is to detach the boot volume, attach it to another host, make your modifications, then re-attach it back as your boot volume and boot. Detailed steps for that workaround are found elsewhere if you need them.

Answer (score 0):

Just edit the bootloader config and reboot the machine like you would do on a locally installed distro.